# Iterating through a list inside a dictionary in Python for an API call

Tags: python

I am pretty new to Python. I have a dictionary that looks like this, with a list inside:

```
"detail": {'items': [['123','item1'],['345','item2']]
```

and I am trying to use the first item in the list for an API call

```
    for x in y["detail"]["items"]:
        url = "https://link/list-of-items/" + x[0]

    payload = {}
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + (parameter['Parameter']['Value'])
    }
        
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    json_object = json.loads(response.text)
```

I have been trying to get the response to be the details of both `item1` and `item2` using  `x[0]`, the first index. How would I go about in doing that?

Comment: In each iteration of the `for` loop, the url variable is reassigned a new value. Therefore after the loop is finished, `url`'s value is https://link/list-of-items/345.

Comment: Unless the API you are talking to supports some kind of batch request, you will need to send multiple requests, meaning all the code goes into the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of the `for` loop, the url variable is reassigned a new value. Therefore after the loop is finished, `url`'s value is https://link/list-of-items/345.

As @Thomas mentioned, you probably need to send multiple requests (one per item), and therefore all the code needs to go into the `for` loop.

In addition, it is important to have meaningful variable names to get readable code.

Putting it all together:

```
for item in iteams_detail["detail"]["items"]:
    url = "https://link/list-of-items/" + item[0]
    payload = {}
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + (parameter['Parameter']['Value'])}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    json_object = json.loads(response.text)
```